# Apache tomcat is not restarting

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I installed Apache tomcat using custom package

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat6
```

I tried restarting the  Apache tomcat 
using this in Ubuntu Terminal

```
sudo service tomcat6 restart
```

then I got the following error

```
Invalid command 'ProxyRequests', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

How do I need to check the error logs

Comment: Please elaborate. It seems like the Apache web server is started,not tomcat. Are you using a custom psckage and/or init script?

Comment: can you tell how do I check whether I am using custom package ,or init script.

Comment: I did using custom package

Comment: There's something I don't quite understand: Madhu13 and Thota Madhu Sudhan Rao are the same person, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
the following as root in the terminal

```
a2enmod proxy
```

and tehn restart

Comment: Are you answering yourself?

Comment: Sorry I answered myself.but that is working [link](http://last-error-message.blogspot.in/2011/02/invalid-command-proxyrequests.html).I found from this link.

Comment: The problem is not with your link. Why are you using two accounts?

Comment: My original account madhuxxxxx@gmail.com is not able to ask answers because one of my question was closed,then I started using new account with sudhanxxxxx@gmail.com for asking questions.Do you mind it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a configuration for apache which is incorrect. I don't know which custom package you installed but check in /etc/apache2/

Maybe do this:

grep -R "ProxyRequests" /etc/apache2/*

See what file this is coming from and fix it. If you don't know what need to be fixed, you can post the output.